Issue building GDB 14.1 On CentOS7
I am trying to build and install GDB 14.1 from source. At the end of the installation, I received the following message.
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./../include/ctf.h ./../include/ctf-api.h '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/info'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./doc/ctf-spec.info '/usr/local/share/info'
 install-info --info-dir='/usr/local/share/info' '/usr/local/share/info/ctf-spec.info'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/programs/gdb-14.1/libctf'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/programs/gdb-14.1/libctf'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install-target'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/programs/gdb-14.1'
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.15' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by gdb)
gdb: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.13' not found (required by gdb)

Could someone kindly help me understand if the installation was successful or not? I am not sure if the not found messages are problematic.

Can you launch your build of gdb? Then there is no problem. Do you have a version of libstdc++.so in    /usr/local/lib? You build of gdb might depend on that version but probably doesn't find it's location. As suggested at the beginning, add that directory to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH
